# Java Swing spacing between objects

Tags: java, swing, layout, space

I have a Java program where i would prefer if i could get a very specific layout.

This is what I get:

JLabel JToggleButon JLabel JToggleButon

This is what I want:

JLabel JToggleButon

JLabel JToggleButon

This is the code:

```
 package Main;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class SystemWindow {
    static JFrame window = new JFrame("System statistics");
    static JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("Push me");
    static JLabel status = new JLabel("Status: ");
    static JLabel status2 = new JLabel("Status: ");
    static JToggleButton button2 = new JToggleButton("Push me");
    static FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    public static void openWindow(){
    window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.add(status);
    window.add(button);
    window.add(status2);
    window.add(button2);
    window.setSize(100, 100);
    window.pack();
    window.setSize(200,70);
    window.setVisible(true);
    while(true){
        status.setText("Status: "+button.isSelected());
            status2.setText("Status: "+button2.isSelected());
        }


    }
}
```

p.s: Wrote the code in eclipse.

Comment: javascript code or java code?

Comment: I write it in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GridLayout where you can specify rows, columns and spacings

i.e. add a jpanel with gridlayout and add these elements inside this panel

```
new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));
```

first parameter is the rows, second the columns and the others are the horizontal and vertical spacing between controls

I guess this works

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));
window.add(panel);
panel.add(status);
panel.add(button);
panel.add(status2);
panel.add(button2);
```

Comment: How would i go ahead and implement this.

Comment: i guess you could do initialize a new panel and instead of window.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); you would add that panel to window. then add all the other controls to that panel

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are getting is the default behaviour for `FlowLayout`. Read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html). Read morea bout layouts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and choose what you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using `GridBayLayout` you have to provide some position constraints when adding controls to container. [Here you have complete guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). 3rd party layout manager as MigLayout should suit your needs too.

```
   while(true){
    status.setText("Status: "+button.isSelected());
        status2.setText("Status: "+button2.isSelected());
    }
```

your computer is going to explode thanks to that code :)